# Dotnet Core 3.1 & CSC: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have to extend an **in-house build system** to compile C# files targeting .Net Core 3.

As of now, the system is capable of processing source sets, references, and lib directories,
where it generates the following command:

```sh
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" exec "C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll" -nologo -target:library "-lib:C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.4" -r:netstandard.dll C:/Users/kirsch/Documents/Repositories/ComplexProject/lib/csharp/native/VeryComplexLogic.cs -out:C:/Users/kirsch/Documents/Repositories/ComplexProject/default/ComplexProject.net.626a237a/ComplexProject.net.dll
```

Sadly, this fails with the following error:

> error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

I tried to search for a solution. The proposed solutions either suggested something, that was not related (like deleting some generated directory), or suggested to add references. Pursuing the latter, I added the following references:

- netstandard.dll
- mscorlib.dll
- System.dll
- System.Core.dll

Referencing these did, however, not solve the problem.

To conclude my question:
**Which reference am I missing?**

**If it's not a reference, what else am I missing then?**

Answer (score 1):

You need `System.Runtime.dll`.

Please note that just providing

```
/lib:"C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.4"
```

is not enough. This is only a directory where the referenced assemblies will be searched for. But you still need to provide each particular referenced assembly by the `/reference` (or `/r`) option:

```
/reference:mscorlib.dll /reference:netstandard.dll /reference:System.Collections.dll /reference:System.Console.dll
```

... etc

MSBuild or `dotnet.exe` do this for you.

Comment: Adding `System.Runtime.dll` (or the other Assemblies you suggested) doesn't solve the issue sadly :(
Any other leads?

Comment: "On my machine, it works". Please post your whole command line.